# stalker python library throws an error for db.session

Tags: python

I'm trying to use stalker for my production company and I seem to not be able to go through the help file.

http://pythonhosted.org/stalker/tutorial.html

when I'm trying the command:

```
db.session.add(myUser)
```

it threw an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    db.session.add()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add'
```

I'm relatively new to python. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in simple terms? Thank you

Comment: Kindly post your complete code so far, so we can try stepping through it versus the documentation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `db.DBSession` instead of `db.session`.

The tutorial you're linking to is already outdated. Stalker is already at version 0.2.6, while the API tutorial you're following is for 0.2.1.

The below code works, which is exactly the same as the one on the tutorial save for last part.

```
from stalker import db, User, Department

db.setup({"sqlalchemy.url":"sqlite:////home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/stalker.db"})

myUser = User(
    name = "Nanashi",
    login = "nanashi",
    email  = "no@name.com",
    password = "none",
    description = "I have no name."
    )

clan = Department(
    name = "Ola",
    description = "We ola you."
    )

clan.members.append(myUser)

db.DBSession.add(myUser)
db.DBSession.add(clan)
db.DBSession.commit()
```

Result after running:

```
DEBUG:stalker.db:settings: {'sqlalchemy.url': 'sqlite:////home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/stalker.db'}
DEBUG:stalker.db:engine: Engine(sqlite:////home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/stalker.db)
DEBUG:stalker.db:creating the tables
DEBUG:stalker.models.auth:name out: nanashi
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

This should work fine for you now. As an additional tip, it is best to check the modules for yourself in case they don't work. For example, exploring the `stalkers` folder and checking out the `sessions.py` file there reveals the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
)

# SQLAlchemy session manager
DBSession = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        extension=None
    )
)
```

That's the entirety of the code. As you've noticed, there's a comment there `# SQLAlchemy session manager` above `DBSession`, which is a massive hint as to what happened to `db.session`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nanashi!, I think this would help, but now I have an even more basic question to ask.

Comment: Thanks Nanashi!, I think this would help, but now I have an even more basic question to ask.

I've installed stalker via this webpage 

[link](http://pythonhosted.org/stalker/installation.html#how-to-install-stalker)

But now when i run idle 
`import stalker`

it says: Import Error : No module named stalker. 

I checked and sys.path includes C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib
but stalker is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27

What should I do? any solutions?

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you. For your other question, it is the practice in SO to start with a new and separate question if the topic is already different from the OP's original question. Even with that said, I'm thinking you should make sure `stalker` is installed into `C:\Python27` and not `C:\Program Files...`. I've never had this problem with my 64-bit installation of `stalker`, even if the answer above was coded in Ubuntu. One other option is to fix your `PYTHONPATH` to check the x86 folder as well.